# Gradle build error: 401 Unauthorized when trying to get plugin from https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release

Tags: spring, gradle

I have a problem with my gradle spring boot project. all of the sudden my builds stopped excecuting successfully. when looking up the problem i encountered a 401 unauthorized when trying to get a spring plugin from

https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release

i have added the repository as following to my build.gradle

`repositories { mavenCentral()  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }   }`

until recently it was working fine. I`ve seen multiple post about unauthorized return codes from this repository but no solution has worked for me so far.

thx for your help.

as i described we did not need to change anything until now. the issue happened on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one:

```
https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/
```

Please mind the trailing slash.

Comment: I still get an error after trying your soluition:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE. Required by: project : > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE. > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom'. > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: